# Assertion failure in UICollectionView when deleting

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, assertion, cs193p

I keep getting an assertion failure when I try to delete cells from my UICollectionView. What I am doing a card game and when the cards match they are to be deleted. I made it so when they match I delete all the matched cards in the model and then delete them from the CollectionView. This is part of Assignment #3 from stanford cs193p course. Here is my code.

Controller Code

```
-(void) updateUI{

NSMutableArray* tempCardToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.cardCollectionView visibleCells]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.cardCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.item);
    Card* card = [self.game cardAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSLog(@"Face up is %d", card.faceUp);
    NSLog(@"%@", card.contents);

// This will update the individual cell with a card value
    [self updateCell:cell usingCard:card];

//cards that are not playable and faceup have been matched so we store them    
if(card.isFaceUp && card.isUnplayable){
        [tempCardToDelete addObject:indexPath];
        self.cardsToDelete = [tempCardToDelete copy];
    }
}
//delete the cards from the model
[self.game deleteMatchedCards];
//delete the cards from the collectionView
if(self.cardsToDelete.count != 0){
     [self.cardCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:self.cardsToDelete];
}

}
```

Model Code

```
-(void) deleteMatchedCards{

//the property stores the cards that should be deleted
for(Card *cards in self.modelCardsToDelete){
    NSUInteger deleteIndex = [self.modelCardsToDelete indexOfObject:cards];
    [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:deleteIndex];
}
}
```

Comment: What is modelCardsToDelete defined as?  Is it supposed to be the same as cardsToDelete?

Comment: What is the full error that you are getting?

Comment: Is the assertion failure from an 'assert' in your code? (And if so where does it appear)

Comment: modelCardsToDelete is an Array of Class Card stored in the model that made a full deck of cards. I store the cards which have been matched in there. CardsToDelete is also an array but stores the IndexPaths of these cards. It obtains the index paths from the controller and checking the unplayable and faceup property

Comment: The full error is  Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionView.m:2801

Comment: may be this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 2):

First Delete the objects form array then delete item from CollectionView 
Code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _totalImagesData.count;   //array from which you are displaying data in collection view
} 


//delete
 [_totalImagesData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
 [self.collectionViewPack deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indPath]];
```